# DISTINCT with DATETIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Logins with the columns (Connection_ID, LogOn), when I run the following query:

```
SELECT Connection_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT LogOn) AS LogOns
FROM Logins 
GROUP BY Connection_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT LogOn) <> 1
```

The output is:

```
--------------------------
| Connection_ID | LogOns |
--------------------------
|     100       |   2    |
--------------------------
|     200       |   2    |
--------------------------
```

But when I check the duplicated times by the following query:

```
SELECT Connection_ID, LogOn FROM Logins WHERE Connection_ID IN (100, 200)
```

I get the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Connection_ID |               LogOns          |
-------------------------------------------------
|     100       |     2019-07-06T13:19:15.16    |
-------------------------------------------------
|     100       |     2019-07-06T13:19:39.94    |
-------------------------------------------------
|     200       |     2019-02-18T21:52:00.253   |
-------------------------------------------------
|     200       |     2019-02-18T21:52:30.27    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the timestamps are not duplicated, they are different, but the first query sees that they are the same, is there any explanation of this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(DISTINCT LogOn)` counts the number of **distinct** values in the column `LogOn`.
You have 2 distinct values in `LogOn` for each of the `Connection_ID`s.
So the result of `COUNT()` is `2`.
Even if you had another 3d row for `Connection_ID = 100` with a duplicate value in `LogOn` the result would still be `2` because only 1 of the duplicates contributes in the results.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is working correctly.  `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is counting the distinct values of `LogOn`.  The "2" is correctly identifying those.  If the values were the same, then `COUNT(DISTINCT logon)` would return `1` rather than `2`.